# Acyclic aspherical spaces with acyclic fundamental groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, localization

A space $X$ (by which I mean a CW complex) is **acyclic** if its reduced singular homology $\tilde H_\ast(X;\Bbb Z)$ is trivial in all degrees.

A discrete group $\pi$ is said to be acyclic if its classifying space $B\pi$ is acyclic.

A space $X$ is **aspherical** if its universal cover is contractible. A space $X$ is **non-aspherical** if its universal cover isn't contractible.

**Question:** Does there exist a *non*-aspherical, acyclic space $X$ whose fundamental group $\pi$ is also acyclic?

Comment: What is the distinction between $\pi$ being acyclic and being perfect? I mean, I see the logical distinction; but are there examples to show that they are actually different concepts?

Comment: I think so, take the binary icosahedral group.

Comment: @JeffStrom Take a look at the Wiki page on perfect groups. In particular, $A_5$ and the groups of elementary infinite matrices over a ring $E(R)$ are both perfect and non-acyclic. For $E(R)$ its $H^2(\mathbb Z)$ is equal to $K_2(R)$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, such things exist. 
Take any finitely presented infinite acyclic group $G$, for example, Higman's group.
It is a theorem by Kervaire (''Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups'') that for each $n \geq 5$, there is an integral homology sphere $M^n$ with fundamental group $G$. Consider $X=M-\ast$. The integral homology of $X$ is trivial, the fundamental group of $X$ is $G$. Suppose that $X$ were  aspherical. Observe that $M\simeq X \cup_f D^n$ is obtained by attaching an $n$-cell. Since $\pi_{n-1} (X)=0$, $f$ is nullhomotopic, and hence $M \simeq S^n \vee X$. It follows that the universal cover of $M$ has the homotopy type of $\tilde{X}$ with infinitely many $S^n$'s attached (since $G$ is infinite). So $H_n (\tilde{M};\mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$, a contradiction, because $\tilde{M}$ is a noncompact $n$-manifold.

Comment: Johannes, it just occurred to me:  why is $\pi_{n-1}(X)$ trivial?

Comment: I just realized you meant to write "aspherical" instead of acyclic.  I fixed your text. It's good now.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I incorporated your change.